# Automate MySQL script on Terminal

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, automation

I'm facing one problem while automating the mysql script. Don't know how to do it.

My script is saved as **Ashish.sql**. I want to automate so that it could run automatically daily on set time. One thing more is that first I need to truncate table**( Table name is "Hash_Sun" where values are being pushed whenever I run the script manually)** before the script runs.

Please help me for the same

Comment: are you asking how to automate the script of how to do it?

Comment: Yes @Amani I have script and want to schedule it for daily run on set time

Answer (score 0):

You can setup cron rule like this:

```
@dayly mysql db_name_here < path_to_sql_file
```

More info here: [Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. allow to execute the file:

   ```
   chmod u+x /path/to/your/file
   ```
2. open crontab

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```
3. Add a new cron job:

   ```
   #MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD
    1    2    3   4   5    /path/to/file
   ```

Example: test.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test";
```

crontab -e: add new line(new job)

```
00 08 * * *   /path/to/script/test.bash
```

this means execute the script daily at 8 AM (If you need to execute the script in a specific time).
Or simply:

```
@daily /path/to/script/test.bash
```

(this is equal: Run once a day, "0 0 * * * ")

Afer adding a new job you have only to save and close cron file, cron will do the rest of the task.
[see more here.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)